# How can I pull specific data from a sourcequery?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the SourceQuery php to query a steam game server however I am hung up on how to make it display the values I want displayed in a table and not the entire array dump.. YES I have tried contacting the creator of this and got no response..

Here is the file I have:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../SourceQuery/bootstrap.php';

use xPaw\SourceQuery\SourceQuery;

Header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
Header( 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff' );

define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', 'localhost' );
define( 'SQ_SERVER_PORT', 27015 );
define( 'SQ_TIMEOUT',     1 );
define( 'SQ_ENGINE',      SourceQuery::SOURCE );

$Query = new SourceQuery( );

try
{
    $Query->Connect( SQ_SERVER_ADDR, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );

    print_r( $Query->GetInfo( ));
    print_r( $Query->GetPlayers( ) );

}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    echo $e->getMessage( );
}
finally
{
    $Query->Disconnect( );
}?>
```

What I am trying to do is put the queried array values in tables like this:

```
<tr>
<td align="center" width="50"><strong>Server Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" width="150"><strong><?php echo $query['name'];?></strong>
```

And this is what shows in the web browser:

```
Array (
[Protocol] => 17
[HostName] => Server 1
[Map] => gm_flatgrass
[ModDir] => garrysmod
[ModDesc] => Sandbox
[AppID] => 4000
[Players] => 0
[MaxPlayers] => 16
[Bots] => 0
[Dedicated] => d
[Os] => l
[Password] => 
[Secure] => 1
[Version] => 18.02.07
[ExtraDataFlags] => 177
[GamePort] => 27015
[SteamID] => 90116597896180737
[GameTags] =>  gm:sandbox
[GameID] => 4000 )
```

Please explain it to me clearly and with the code examples I provided.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the exambles they provide they do it like this,
make an array, and then populate them with the server info.

```
$Query = new SourceQuery( );

$Info    = Array( );
$Players = Array( );

try
{
    $Query->Connect( SQ_SERVER_ADDR, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );

    $Info    = $Query->GetInfo();
    $Players = $Query->GetPlayers();
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    $Exception = $e;
}
finally
{
    $Query->Disconnect( );
}
```

Source: https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query/blob/master/Examples/View.php

Then show the info from the arrays that got populated.

```
<tr>
<td align="center" width="50"><strong>Server Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" width="150"><strong><?php echo $Info['HostName'];?></strong>
```

Comment: Yes I know but that example dumps ALL if the server info into the table. I do not want all of it to be shown

Comment: Look at how i cut out the parts you need from the example and added it to your html :) the `$Info` part where i look for `HostName` that you can see in the list you posted above. 1. make an variable named Info. 2. then push the content from `$Query->GetInfo()`into it. 3. then you can use it in your html, like `<span><?php echo $Info['Key']; ?></span>`